# Unable to give Billing Administrator role to my account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-billing

I would like to setup Budget and Alert for one of the client project. I think I have all the relevant roles like owner, project IAM admin, Organization admin but still I am unable to give/get Billing Administrator role

Attached screenshot with list of roles I have
[image]

Attached another screenshot where I am still not getting

> Billing Account Administrator

and I see only

> Project Billing Manager

[image]

I followed this documentation (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/job-functions/billing) and it clearly says CEO (who is Organization Administrator) can grant Office Manager, **Billing Account Administrator** role. But here I am unable to assign Billing Account Administrator role to myself. Can any one guide me how should I proceed to set Budgets & Alerts? Also I have enabled Cloud Billing API

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please, be aware that the `Billing Account Administrator` role can only be granted at the [organization or billing account levels](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access#overview-of-cloud-billing-roles-in-cloud-iam), not to a project, as it seems you are trying to do per your screenshot.

If you have the necessary permissions, please, select your organization in the top projects dropdown in the GCP Web console, and then the option `IAM & Admin`: from there, you should have the ability to `ADD` the required role.